# Any example of how to integrate Qt in some ROS package?

Tags: qt, cmake

I would like to use an QT as an user interface for my mobile platform. I have a sensor package consist of IMU , Laser, Kinect and wheel encoders. Would like to have an input button that run a rose node than do something with the data and gives an output results. I was told that should set up like any other Qt + CMake project.

I have used the simple example

```
  #include "QDebug"
    #include "ros/ros.h"

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      ros::init(argc, argv, "Qt_test");
      qDebug()<<"Hello world";
        return 0;
    }


Than successfuly made the CmakeList file. I could compile it with make. But when I tried to run it  with `./test_qt` I got this error

    bash: ./test_qt: No such file or directory
```

An help
Thanks

Comment: Qt4 or Qt5? For Qt4, Google gives e.g. http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects

Comment: I edit the error I got when tried to run in the simple QT example

Answer (score 0):

You must use some package like this http://wiki.ros.org/qt_tutorials?distro=hydro.
And using cmake for build your project. In the case who you want use qtcreator you must call the ide by a command-line. But before, your bash must know the path of ROS installation.

1 - type that in your bash: source devel.setup.bash
2 - create your qtRos node/package in your catkin workspace.
3 - call qtcreator in command line